# Django Filter on Distinct with orderby created at

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

How can I filter with distinct and order by

```
IncomingCallRecording.objects.filter().order_by("lead_id","-created_at").distinct("lead_id")
```

**Problem:**
Order by is not working with created at

Is there an alternative solution that might help

Comment: What sort of error are you getting. Also are you using PostGres?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `created_at` in `order_by`.

```
IncomingCallRecording.objects.order_by("-created_at").distinct("lead_id")
```

Multiple columns sorting is done in sequence. If you define two columns in `order_by`, it sorts by first column and then second column (first by `lead_id`, and then within each `lead_id` sort by `created_at`).

**Update**

The solution would be subjected to database. For MYSQL, `DISTINCT ON` isn't allowed. For POSTGRES, `DISTINCT ON` expression must match `ORDER BY`.

In case of `POSTGRES`, you will need to use `Subquery`, if you would like to use different `DISTINCT ON` and `ORDER BY` expressions.

```
IncomingCallRecording.objects.filter(
    pk__in=Subquery(
       IncomingCallRecording.objects.distinct('lead_id').values('pk')
    )
).order_by('-created_at')
```

Comment: Yep but its not working: ``` SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON```

Comment: Database you are using?

Comment: I'm using postgresql for now

Comment: Right! You may need to use `Subquery`. I am updating answser.